# I got error on 'filter' but not on 'for'..WHY??(error: the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time')

Tags: swift

I'm a newbie to swift programming.
I'm trying to get string with the only letters("a-z", "A-Z"), numbers("0-9"), and "-", "_", "*".

when I first tried this code

```swift
var new_id = "abc123##%%.."
    new_id.filter { ($0 >= "a" && $0 <= "z") || ($0 >= "0" && $0 <= "9") || $0 == "-" || $0 == "_" || $0 == "." }
```

I got this error

> error: the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

I searched out this error and found out I should break up this code.
However, when I try the below code, actually it works..!

```swift
for i in 0..<new_id.count {
    let ch: Character = new_id[new_id.index(new_id.startIndex, offsetBy: i)]
    if ( (ch >= "a" && ch <= "z") || (ch >= "0" && ch <= "9") || ch == "-" || ch == "_" || ch == "." ) {
        new_new_id.append(ch)
    }
}
```

Then, what's the difference between these two codes? I thought the above 'filter' function works same with the below code with 'for'
statement.

Comment: In the first case, new_id is not an array.

Comment: not a direct answer to your question but you can simply use `{ "a"..."z" ~= $0 || "0"..."9" ~= $0 || $0 == "-" || $0 == "_" || $0 == "." }` or even simpler `{ "a"..."z" ~= $0 || "0"..."9" ~= $0 || "-_.".contains("$0") }`

Comment: This is probably because of some obscure implementation details in the Swift compiler. Processing a single expression closure _probably_ takes more steps. If you just change the `filter` closure to `if ... { return true } else { return false }` then it works too.

Comment: @Sweeper I think it is related to the fact that if there is a single line (closure) it tries to infer the resulting type

Comment: use Regression instead of filter

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali definitely not. Note that regex it is not native Swift. It requires you to import Foundation

Comment: @LeoDabus Does it actually do that? I know it does that for cases where the result type _has_ to be inferred, but in this case it doesn't really _need_ to infer the result type, since `filter` is declared to take a closure that returns a `Bool`, right? This is why I'm not too sure what extra processing it needs to do.

Comment: yes but using regression will reduce your most Headache... even working with email validation password validations etc

Comment: Btw filter is probably also much faster than a regex

Comment: try DispatchQueue.main.asyc { "Your Filter Code" }

Comment: ```let data = newString.filter({$0 == "e"})
        print(data.count)```

Comment: You cannot use $0 <= "a"  in filter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237160/discussion-between-noor-ahmed-natali-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali why not? it would result in `"abc\n"`

Comment: @Sweeper It's really interesting that using `if ... { return true } else { return false }` instead of single expression closure did work, though it is still hard for me to understand why single expression closure need more steps ...

Answer (score -1):

````
        let newString = "Hello123..H##^^%%"
        
        
        let StringData = newString.filter({$0.isLetter})
        let NumericData = newString.filter({$0.isNumber})
        let caseData = newString.filter({$0 == "_" || $0 == "-" || $0 == "."})
        
        
        
        let ChekedData = newString.filter({$0.isNumber || $0.isLetter || $0 == "_" || $0 == "-" || $0 == "."})
        
        print(StringData)
        print(NumericData)
        print(caseData)
        
        print(ChekedData) ```
````

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, what's the difference for swift compiler between `$0.isNumber` and `(ch >= "a" && ch <= "z")`  in single expression closure?

Comment: isNumber Check whether $0 (char in a string) is a number or not... if it is a number it will  store it